# Adding setForeground on TextView in Recyclerview , sometimes it's not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to setForeground over TextView in Recyclerview , but sometimes it's not working when i scroll up to down or vice versa . see screenshot for more information .

1)when data load first time it look like :
[image]

2)when i scroll up and then down its look like this:
[image]

My Adapter class code :

```
public class ChatAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.MessageViewHolder>  {

    private List<FriendlyMessageModel> friendlyMessageModelList;
    private String android_id;
    public Context context;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<FriendlyMessageModel> friendlyMessageModelList) {
        this.friendlyMessageModelList = friendlyMessageModelList;
        FireBaseSetup fireBaseSetup = new FireBaseSetup();
        android_id = fireBaseSetup.getUID();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);

        return new MessageViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        FriendlyMessageModel friendlyMessageModel = friendlyMessageModelList.get(position);
        String author =  friendlyMessageModel.getName();
        boolean isPhoto = friendlyMessageModel.getPhotoUrl()!=null;

        if(author.equals(android_id))
        {
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            params1.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        }
        else{
            params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            params1.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        }

        if (params.gravity == Gravity.RIGHT) {
            if(isPhoto)
            {
                holder.ivPhoto.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner1));
                holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(holder.ivPhoto.getContext())
                        .load(friendlyMessageModel.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(holder.ivPhoto);

            }
            else {
                holder.tvMessage.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner1));
                holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //holder.tvMessage.setLayoutParams(params);
                holder.tvMessage.setText(friendlyMessageModel.getText());

            }

        }else{
            if(isPhoto)
            {
                holder.ivPhoto.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner2));
                holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.tvMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(holder.ivPhoto.getContext())
                        .load(friendlyMessageModel.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(holder.ivPhoto);
            }
            else {
                holder.tvMessage.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner2));
                holder.ivPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.tvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //holder.tvMessage.setLayoutParams(params);
                holder.tvMessage.setText(friendlyMessageModel.getText());
            }
        }
        holder.tvAuthor.setLayoutParams(params);
        holder.tvAuthor.setText(friendlyMessageModel.getName());

        // TODO: 21/2/18 added by kd
        final int color = Color.parseColor("#FADA5E");
        final Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(color);

        if(!friendlyMessageModel.isHide()){
            holder.confidemsg.setForeground(drawable);
            holder.confidemsg.setLayoutParams(params1);
            // TODO: 21/2/18 added by kd  confide feature
            holder.confidemsg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            holder.confidemsg.setForeground(null);
                            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            // RELEASED
                            holder.confidemsg.setForeground(drawable);
                            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                            holder.confidemsg.setForeground(drawable);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


            // TODO: 21/2/18 added by kd  confide feature
            holder.confideimg.setForeground(drawable);
            holder.confideimg.setLayoutParams(params1);
            holder.confideimg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            // PRESSED
                            holder.confideimg.setForeground(null);
                            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            // RELEASED
                            holder.confideimg.setForeground(drawable);
                            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                            holder.confideimg.setForeground(drawable);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }


//        Calendar currnetDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
//        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
//        String  currentTime = df.format(currnetDateTime.getTime());
//
//        holder.tvTime.setLayoutParams(params);
//        holder.tvTime.setText(currentTime);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return friendlyMessageModelList.size();
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivPhoto;
        TextView tvMessage, tvAuthor, tvTime;
        // TODO: 21/2/18 added by kd
        //CardView confide;
        FrameLayout confidemsg, confideimg;

        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
            tvMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            tvAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            tvTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);

            //todo added by kd
            confidemsg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.confidemsg);
            confideimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.confideimg);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is just simple , how to solve problem in 2nd screenshot . whenever i scroll up and down it's always shown .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you scrolling the `RecyclerView` intercept the `TouchEvent` so you won't receive the `ACTION_UP`.

The best way to set a `TouchListener` on an Item is to set an [`ItemTouchHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) to `RecyclerView` itself overriding `onChildDraw` method.

Answer (score 0):

when you scroll up and down in recycler view that time recyclerview adapter call onBindViewHolder() method in every time.there for your color setup on textview put inside onBindViewHolder().

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

 }
```

Comment: Thank You for replaying , i already placed my code inside onBindViewHolder .

Comment: then you make one variable in pojo class that hold color value and check if that color then textview set that color in onBindViewHolder()method.

Comment: then pl provide your full code of adapter class then i try it.

Answer (score 0):

i done some simple changes and only check back ground color and it working fine try below code and test it and is working not change scolling time..

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

private List<String> friendlyMessageModelList;
private String android_id;
public Context context;

public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<String> friendlyMessageModelList) {
    this.friendlyMessageModelList = friendlyMessageModelList;
    //FireBaseSetup fireBaseSetup = new FireBaseSetup();
    //android_id = fireBaseSetup.getUID();
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);

    return new MessageViewHolder(itemView);
}

@SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "ResourceAsColor"})
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    String friendlyMessageModel = friendlyMessageModelList.get(position);
```

//        String author =  friendlyMessageModel.getName();
        //      boolean isPhoto = friendlyMessageModel.getPhotoUrl()!=null;

```
    if (friendlyMessageModel.equals("black")) {
        holder.tvTime.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    }
```

//        Calendar currnetDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
//        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
//        String  currentTime = df.format(currnetDateTime.getTime());
//
//        holder.tvTime.setLayoutParams(params);
//        holder.tvTime.setText(currentTime);
    }

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return friendlyMessageModelList.size();
}

class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivPhoto;
    TextView tvTime;

    // TODO: 21/2/18 added by kd
    //CardView confide;
    public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeData);

        //todo added by kd
    }
}
```

}

Comment: friendlyMessageModel is Model .

Comment: it just string object for testing you can pass your model class also.

Comment: it's showing all text , i want to hide , it's visible when user touch on it.

Comment: that time when you touch any item that remove form the list and notify adapter then it will be not show in recyclerview.